# windows explorer shell integration and bit more?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, shell

I have registered a program in windows explorer right click menu using this link. [.NET-Shell-Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus), It works fine. But my problem is I want to target XML file, If I right click on that file it will load that XML file and  open fileDialog to choose folder and create folder and sub-folder according to the structure of the XML file. It looks fine when I tasted it on shell server. I tried to register with this following code but its not appearing when I click on any XML file.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpShell.Attributes;
using SharpShell.SharpContextMenu;
using System.Xml;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".xml")]
public class Class1 : SharpContextMenu
{
    protected override bool CanShowMenu()
    {
        return true;
    }     
    protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {          
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        var createFolder = new ToolStripMenuItem
        {
            Text = "Create Folder",                
        };                      
        createFolder.Click += (sender, args) => myFunction();
        menu.Items.Add(createFolder);
        return menu;
    }
    private void myFunction()
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        foreach (var filePath in SelectedItemPaths)
        {             
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                string fullPath = ofd.FileName;               
                using (XmlTextReader reader = new  XmlTextReader(fullPath))
                {
                    var basePath = filePath + "/";
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:                           
                                var baseDirPath = Path.Combine(basePath + reader.Name);
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDirPath);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Text: 
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath + reader.Name + "/" + reader.Value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }        
    }
}
```

}